# Oracle BMCS object store bandwidth cost

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

If my application that run in oracle bare metal compute nodes access oracle bare metal object storage service using the http apis provided, would it incur bandwidth cost? In other words, is there a way the compute nodes can route the traffic through an internal network rather than going through public IPs of the bare metal object storage service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no charge for network traffic between OBMCS compute and the object store.

Comment: *citation needed*

Comment: @Craig Carl: What does that mean from a security point of view? Is there a mechanism that prevent traffic from looping into public internet and back to OBMCS object store?

Comment: Traffic from public IP addresses to public IP addresses in the same region never leaves the local BMC network. I'll have a note to that effect added to the documentation and add that reference here.

Comment: Nick A - You are right, I'll get the pricing page(s) clarified and add a link here.

Comment: @CraigCarl : Thanks for the prompt response. What would happen if the compute node does not have a public IP?

Comment: @NNSB You will want to use a proxy. You should create a subnet with Internet access, put a instance (1 oCPU VM is fine) in that subnet with squid installed and configure your instance to use that proxy. If you are using RMAN to backup your Oracle DB RMAN can be configured to use the proxy, that way the OS is still isolated but RMAN can get to the object store. Assuming you need a bastion to get to that "private" instance the squid instance can also be used for that, good secondary use case.